# Get-AzureRmSqlServerAuditing: The term 'Get-AzSqlServerAuditing' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cli, azure-sql-server

I want to check the auditing status of the SQL server using the Azure CLI command.

I have SQL Server named 'dummy-sql' inside resource group 'group1'.

So According to this link,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqlserverauditing?view=azps-2.8.0

When I tried this Powershell command,

Get-AzureRmSqlServerAuditing -ResourceGroupName "group1" -ServerName "dummy-sql"

I got this error,

**Get-AzureRmSqlServerAuditing: The term 'Get-AzSqlServerAuditing' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

How to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get-AzSqlServerAuditing** is deprecated You need to use [**`Get-AzSqlServerAudit`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqlserveraudit?view=azps-5.5.0) instead

```
Get-AzSqlServerAudit -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup01" -ServerName "server01"
```

Read from [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqlserveraudit?view=azps-5.5.0)